# Hydrogen radial wave function in Feynman

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, hydrogen

I'm reading the classical [Feynman's lectures on hydrogen atom](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/III_19.html), and I want to calculate the radial component of the wave function with the formula (19.53)

$$
F_{n,l}(\rho)=\frac{e^{-\alpha\rho}}{\rho}\sum_{k=l+1}^n a_k \rho^k
$$
for $n=2$ and $l=1$.
So I have $\alpha=1/n=1/2$ and
$$
F_{2,1}(\rho)=\frac{e^{-\rho/2}}{\rho}a_2 \rho^2
$$
where $a_2$  should be given by the formula (19.50):
$$
a_{k+1} =\frac{2(\alpha k-1)}{k(k+1)-l(l+1)} a_k
$$
but, for $k+1=2$ and $l=1$ the denominator becomes $0$.

It seems that I have some stupid mistake, but I don't see where. Someone can help me?

Comment: The lower limit of the sum in your first equation requires...

Comment: It's k = l + 1, so k = 2, not k + 1 = 2 (which is the forbidden k = l case).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is just a simple arithmetic error. It's  *k = l + 1* so *k = 2* (for the l = 1 case) , not *k + 1 = 2* (which is the forbidden k = l).

Comment: But, since $\alpha=1/2$, for $k=2$ the recursion  formula gives $a_3=0$. And it's wrong.

Comment: @EmilioNovati why is it wrong? $k$ is supposed to span $\{l+1,...,n\}$, i.e. $\{2\}$. I.e., there's only one term in the whole sum. The values of $a_k$ other than $a_2$ are irrelevant. Or, well, since you're using an upwards recurrence relation, then the values of $a_k$ for $k>n$ are irrelevant.

Comment: I see. But my problem is: if I take $k+1=2$ the recurrence gives $a_2=-1/(1\cdot 2-1\cdot 2)$ and if i take $k=2$ the recurrence gives $a_2=0$. And I don't see where is the mistake.

Comment: @EmilioNovati You can't take *k + 1 = 2* for the *l = 1* case. It's the *l = 1, k=1* case which the text explicitly addresses in the line "The index k cannot be equal to l, the denominator becomes zero and al+1 is infinite." If you get *a2 = 0* and all later terms are also zero this is perfectly legitimate, not a sign that anything has gone wrong.

Comment: Now I understand!! (I hope). We have to choose $a_2$, that is the first step in the recursion, say $a_2=1$. Then we can use the recursive formula. Correct?